# Your phone can't connet to the WiFi network HOMENET

Tags: wifi

I've just realised that the reason why my apps weren't updating even though I was at home is because the phone can't connect to my home WiFi.

I'm not sure why, as previously there was no problem.

- I've tried restarting the router.
- I've checked the router works with a different device.
- I've tried deleting and recreating in Settings > WiFi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Had to reboot the phone. Don't ask me why.